# Backup my org all the customisation or create an image

Tags: ant, workbench, backup

I have to backup all my Salesforce org customization . Is it possible to backup or create an image or both my Salesforce org customization with the reports and dashboards of the org.

Also , is it possible to do this on regular basis automatically.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do it depending on your exact use cases including

1) Use 3rd party solutions such as [Spanning](http://spanning.com/products/salesforce-backup/), [Datto](http://www.datto.com/backupify/salesforce-backup), [OwnBackup](https://www.ownbackup.com/products/backup-for-salesforce) etc. Some of these offer scheduling so you can do it on a defined periodicity.

2) Built in Data Export feature. Follow [this](https://www.shellblack.com/administration/data-export/) tutorial for more details.

3) You can individually export Reports data as well using the [Export a Report](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_export.htm&language=en_US) feature

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors you should consider when looking for a backup and recovery solution for Salesforce:

1. It’s all about the recovery. The tool needs to have seamless **recovery back to Salesforce**, no matter what the data loss scenario. The tool should be able to restore any number of records, including all **parent child relationships**.
2. It should also be able to restore field level changes on records that may have been accidentally or maliciously over-written. When in doubt, take it for a ride and test it out.
3. Make sure that you will have access to your backup snapshot even if your Salesforce instance is down (On May 9, 2016 - the Salesforce instance NA14 was down for almost the entire day [More details can be found in the link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Root-Cause-Message-for-Disruption-of-Service-on-NA14-May-2016&language=en_US))